# Add a word to a string based on a conditional statement

Tags: r, string, if-statement, character

I'm trying to add a word to the end of a string based on an ifelse statement and having trouble.

```
words <- c("one","two","one","four")
newword <- "word"
```

and then if the value equals "one", I want to append a word

```
words <- ifelse(words == "one",
                gsub(paste(newword, sep = " "), "", words),
                words)
```

I want the output to be

```
words
[1] "one word"  "two"  "one word"  "four"
```

any idea why I can't make this happen with an ifelse and the paste() function?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you do not need to use ifelse. You can try `gsub(x = words, pattern = "(one)", replacement = paste("\\1", newword, sep = " "))`, for example. Or you can do something like `words[which(words == "one")] <- paste("one", newword, sep = " ")`.

Comment: Amazing.  Thank you!

Comment: @jazzuro can you make your comment an answer please so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry I was not here for some time. I am happy to file the code above as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write up my ideas since the OP requested it. One way is to use `gsub()`. You look for the pattern, "one" and replace it by pasting "one", which is represented as `\\1`, and newword. The other way is to use `which()`. You look for index numbers for the element, "one". For those index number positions, you want to add `paste("one", newword, sep = " ")`.

```
gsub(x = words, pattern = "(one)", replacement = paste("\\1", newword, sep = " "))

words[which(words == "one")] <- paste("one", newword, sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both `gsub` and `paste`.

Here's how to do it with `ifelse` and `paste` (this is probably how I would do it):

```
ifelse(words == "one", paste(words, newword), words)
# [1] "one word" "two"      "one word" "four"
```

Here's how to do it with just `paste`. (Creating a new variable just so the original object stays unchanged for the next method.)

```
words2 = words
words2[words2 == "one"] = paste(words2[words2 == "one"], newword)
words2
# [1] "one word" "two"      "one word" "four"
```

And here's how to do it with just `gsub`:

```
gsub(pattern = "(one)", x = words, replacement = paste("\\1", newword))
# [1] "one word" "two"      "one word" "four"
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor!  The ifelse still didn't work for me, but the gsub is perfect like in the comment above.